# Resolve the combined promise when some of them gets resolved

Tags: javascript, promise

I have three promises. I need to combine them together to create one more promise.

Something like this  `Promise.all('url1','url2','url3')` or if there is other possible way to achieve it.

Intent is to fire all of them in parallel.

I have requirement that when either two of them are resolved, then the final one will be resolved.

How I can achieve it?

Comment: Promise.all takes an **array** (of promises and/or values) as an argument

Comment: So if you have `n` promises either `n-1` of them resolves the last remaining one must resolve afterwards is this what you mean..? What kind of task exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a requirement that I wanted fire some fetch request which are requesting to different server. Different server hosts certain types of data. Which ever data sets comes first resolve the promise. There are some combinations as well in my requirement. I wanted to know whether any proven pattern exists for such scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might give you an idea. You have the chance to run the first resolving promise and the last one. But the logic is straightforward and you may play as you wish. I haven't included the error handling rejection logic but that should be fairly easy.

The `bring()` function returns a promise resolving in 100~200ms.

```js
var bring = n => new Promise(v => setTimeout(v,~~(Math.random()*100)+100,`from url_${n}`)),
    pcnt  = 0,
    proms = Array.from({length: 10})
                 .map((_,i) => bring(i).then(v => ++pcnt === 1 ? (console.log(`Do stg with the 1st resolving promise ${v} immediately`), [pcnt,v])
                                                               : pcnt < proms.length ? console.log(`Do nothing with intermediate resolving promise ${v}`)
                                                                                     : (console.log(`Do stg with the last resolving promise ${v} finally\n`), [pcnt,v])
                                            )
                     );

Promise.all(proms)
       .then(vs => console.log("Or when all completes, deal with the values returned from the first and last promise\n",vs.filter(d => !!d)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to come up with a promise that resolves when, for example, 2 of 3 promises resolve. Promise.all wouldn't be the right thing to use because, well, you *aren't* waiting for all the promises to resolve. You'd have to do it manually:

```js
const resolveAfterSeconds = function(sec) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(res, sec * 1000)
  })
}

new Promise((resolve) => {
  const promises = [
    resolveAfterSeconds(1),
    resolveAfterSeconds(2),
    resolveAfterSeconds(3),
  ];
  let resolveCount = 0;
  promises.forEach(prom => {
    prom.then(() => {
      console.log('resolving');
      resolveCount++;
      if (resolveCount === promises.length - 1) resolve();
    });
  });
}).then(() => console.log('done'));
```

Comment: There are *so* many edge cases that this code doesn't handle - please don't use it.

Comment: @Bergi Of course this is just a simple example with no error/reject handling, but what are the edge cases you're thinking of?

Comment: Well, yes, rejections are one very important case. `promises.length == 0` is another. And there are probably more.